# How to pass a variable into a MongoDB query where it should be a property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, properties, mern

Below is a code snippet from an express route of a MERN application that uses mongojs to manage the database. In order to properly store data I have a collection called "shows" that is to consist of 3 subcategories (watching, watched, and queued) that each consist of an array of objects.

Obviously 3 separate post routes could accomplish this same task but is there a way to modify this query where "shows.watched" can be passed a variable and not declared as a property within this query?

I'm thinking along the lines of using the local variable `var something` to create the request "shows.queued". Something similar to JSX's ability to concatenate via `shows.${id}` or bypassing the standard property request in the query would work but not sure of the best approach in MongoDB.

```
app.post('/saveshow/:save', function(req, res) {
var something = "queued";
db.users.findAndModify(
    {query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body.userId)},
    update : { $push : { **"shows.watched"** : {showid : 
    req.body.saveId, showtitle : req.body.saveTitle, 
    showimage : req.body.saveImage}}}}, 
function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
res.json(result);
    })
});
```

This will correctly pass into the database the collections

shows -> watched -> [{"showid": "..."}, {"showtitle":"..."}] etc.

Just looking for an easier way to scale if possible.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the $push part of your query first, as a javascript object, you can dynamically adjust where the data gets saved:

```js
let subcategory = req.subcategory; // e.g. "watched"
let dataChanges = {};
dataChanges[subcategory] = {showid : req.body.saveId, etc};
// dataChanges is now an object structured like this:
// { watched : {showId: 12345} }
db.users.findAndModify(
  {
    query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body.userId)},
    update : {$push: {dataChanges} }
   }
) etc.
```

This is one of the real strengths of MongoDB; the query language json is so very easy to put together in javascript code.